# changing the backicon in android with renderer generates nullreference

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to change the backicon in android using the next code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Project;
using Project.Droid;
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), 
typeof(NavigationPageRendererDroid))]
namespace Project.Droid
{
public class NavigationPageRendererDroid : PageRenderer
{
    ActionBar actionBar;
    public NavigationPageRendererDroid(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        actionBar = ((Android.App.Activity)Context).ActionBar;

        Console.WriteLine(actionBar);
        actionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.CustomNavigationBarLayout);
        actionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        // This function is used for hide the App Icon
        actionBar.SetIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent.ToAndroid()));

        Element.Appearing += (object sender, EventArgs ex) => {
            // Update Title and Back Icon when user go back to this page
            UpdatePageTitle();

            UpdateBackIcon();
        };
    }

    void UpdateBackIcon()
    {
        var actionBar = ((Android.App.Activity)Context).ActionBar;
        if (actionBar == null || actionBar.CustomView == null)
            return;


        // If you want to hide the back button in some pages, 
        // you can pass a value to renderer and do this.

            actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.LeftArrow);

    }

    void UpdatePageTitle()
    {
        var actionBar = ((Android.App.Activity)Context).ActionBar;
        if (actionBar == null || actionBar.CustomView == null)
            return;

        var view = actionBar.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TitleText);
        if (view != null)
            view.Text = Element.Title;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        // As we used customer view, so Title cannot be update after page loaded.
        if (e.PropertyName == "Title")
            UpdatePageTitle();

    }
}
```

}

but I get the error of nullreference in this line of code

```
actionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.CustomNavigationBarLayout);
```

and have defined CustomNavigationBarLayout in Resources folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and doesn't recognize android:orientation, however, if I erase this line I still obtain the nullreference error in the actionBar.SetCustomView()

Comment: Is it actionBar which is null?

Comment: sincerely, I don't know when I compile it oes it so fast that I can see the Console.WriteLine();

Comment: sincerely, I don't know when I compile it oes it so fast that I can't see the Console.WriteLine();

Comment: Add breakpoint and see what is null

Comment: Or what Console.WriteLine(actionBar); writes?

Comment: console.writeline() doesnt write anything at leat what I see, but moves very fast, I will check the breaking point

Comment: actionbar is null

Comment: do you have any idea how initialize it to make it don't null?

Comment: I was using same rendered a little bit different. ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage) and I extend NavigationRenderer instead of PageRenderer. But checked and it looks that it works both ways. What I suggest, try to skip if it is null. For me it stops about 3 times till my application launches. So maybe on your side it fails to get it first time, but second time it will find it. so just add if(actionBar==null) return; and see what will happen

Comment: One possible idea: your first page does not have action bar, it is fullscreen, so you get null, because you override too generic ContentPage. So changing to NavigationPage like in comment above might solve problem

Comment: in base.OnElementChanged(e); I am getting System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.